# Weird spacing between words in a sentence

Tags: spacing, xetex, awesome-cv

So I am using the [Awesome-CV](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template to create my resume and I am having trouble getting rid of the weird spacing that happens when there is not enough words to fill a line.

As you can below, the spacing in the red boxes below have different spacing based on the words in the sentence on that line. Pretty much I need spaces to be equal lengths.

Would love if anyone could help me out with this as it is driving me nuts.

[image]

This is the code for the macro.

```
    % Define an environment for cventry
    \newenvironment{cventries}{%
      \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    }{%
    }
    % Define an entry of cv information
    % Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
    \newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
      \vspace{-2.0mm}
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
      \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
        \ifempty{#2#3}
          {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
          {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
          \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
      \end{tabular*}%
    }

    % Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
    \newenvironment{ItemNormalSize}{%
      \vspace{-4.0mm}
      \begin{justify}
      \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=4ex, nosep, noitemsep]
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
        \normalsize
    }{%
      \end{itemize}
      \end{justify}
      \vspace{-4.0mm}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: For equal-length spaces, drop the use of your `justify` environment and instead issue `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 1):

The online source you point to has no environment `ItemNormalSize`, so you must have defined this yourself. As such, you would have control over changing it.

You should remove the `justify` environment within your definition and rather use `\raggedright`:

```
% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{ItemNormalSize}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \raggedright
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=4ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
    \normalsize
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
```